# Swift 3 change to NSErrorPointer?

Tags: swift, error-handling, swift3

I have code I've been using for SwiftyJSON and I'm trying to update to Swift 3 using XCode 8.0 Beta 3. I'm running into an issue where the compiler doesn't like the argument 'error: &err' as it did before. I've been searching for how to correctly pass an NSErrorPointer but everything I've found says to re-write, leave out the error and throw an error back. Since this isn't my code I'd rather leave it as it is. So what's the correct new way to use an NSErrorPointer?

```
var err : NSError?
// code to get jsonData from file
let json = JSON(data: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments, error: &err)
if err != nil {
   // do something with the error
} else {
    return json
}
```

The code above results in compiler error: '&' can only appear immediately in a call argument list. I've tried creating an NSErrorPointer so I can use that instead but I can't find anything on how to initialize one (the type alias declaration is not enough). I've already been to [Using Swift with Cocoa and Obj-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html), it does not contain the word NSErrorPointer, instead goes over the new way of throwing errors. I've also looked over a couple dozen posts all using the &err so apparently this is new to Swift 3.

Is there anyone out there that's solved this one? What's the answer to using NSErrorPointer?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That seems to be an error in the Swift 3 branch of SwiftyJSON at

- https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/swift3/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift

which defines the init method as

```
public init(data:Data, options opt: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = .allowFragments, error: NSErrorPointer? = nil) {
    do {
        let object: AnyObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: opt)
        self.init(object)
    } catch let aError as NSError {
        if error != nil {
            error??.pointee = aError
        }
        self.init(NSNull())
    }
}
```

In the Swift 3 that comes with Xcode 8 beta 3, `NSErrorPointer` is an optional:

```
public typealias NSErrorPointer = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?>?
```

as a consequence of

- [SE-0055: Make unsafe pointer nullability explicit using Optional](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0055-optional-unsafe-pointers.md)

Therefore the `error` parameter should have the type `NSErrorPointer`,
not `NSErrorPointer?` (and consequently `error??.pointee`
changed to `error?.pointee`).
With these changes the init method becomes

```
public init(data:Data, options opt: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = .allowFragments, error: NSErrorPointer = nil) {
    do {
        let object: AnyObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: opt)
        self.init(object)
    } catch let aError as NSError {
        if error != nil {
            error?.pointee = aError
        }
        self.init(NSNull())
    }
}
```

and then your code compiles and runs as expected.

Comment: Thanks so much for the details in the answer. Looks like SwiftyJSON duplicated the efforts outlined in SE-0055 that was done by the change to the type alias.